# Checking user authentication in Page_Load()... anywhere else?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms

For each page in my ASP.Net WebForms app I check the user's access like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!UserCanAccessPage())
        RedirectToAccessNotPermitted();

    // < if user has access, set up the page >
}
```

My question is, is that single check enough or should I check at all other handlers:

```
protected void seriousDeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // ** DO I NEED TO CHECK ACCESS AGAIN HERE? **

    // < do stuff that only some users have access to >
}
```

I know under a normal page lifecycle the `Page_Load()` should always be called before the event handlers, but I'm wondering if there's a tricky way to hit other ASP.NET endpoints with `curl` or mucking around with javascript or something.

(I'm only talking about regular WebForms-style postbacks, no explicit AJAX stuff. But of course `UpdatePanel` uses asynchronous javascript and I'm sure other controls do to.)

Comment: Sounds like you reinvent builtin authentication and authorization mechanisms. Why don't just switch to existing, forms authentication based approach?

Comment: We do use built-in authentication ("Windows" auth) to make sure all users are authenticated. I'm talking about more fine-graned access control to specific pages and features, like "project managers can only make changes to projects they're in charge of" or something. That sort of thing needs to be done in code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is enough, because Page_Load will be called every time a user requests a new page or posts back the page. You do not need to check again in button click events.

However, it is fine with a website with a couple of pages. In other words, if you have multiple pages, maintenance is will be nightmare.

Normally, you want to use [Form Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and restrict acesss to pages by using web.config.

Comment: OK, good to know that there are no short-cuts to the event handler. (We do use built-in authentication; see my response to @WiktorZychla's comment on the question.